# How to convert this function from Excel to Open Office?

Tags: excel, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I got this function from folks that use Excel and can't get it to work in Open Office. Do you guys have any clue to find the error? I always get "#NAME?" as output. The [function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_MID_function) is supposed to take a few entries from the cell value and add it together with other values to a new date.

```
=date(mid(F3;7;4);left(F3;2);mid(F3;4;2))
```

Comment: Could be that Open Office requires commas instead of semicolons. Did you try changing your formula to include commas?

Comment: what language is your open office?

Comment: the open office language is in swedish, would it help to change? I also tried to replace the semicolons with commas, but returned in other erros. following the documentation for OO it looks like they require semicolons actually

Comment: What is in cell F3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work in Apache OpenOffice.  Be sure the numbers for `MID` are correct.

For example, say the following text is in A1.

```
year is 2018, month is 02, day is 19
```

This formula produces a date.

```
=DATE(MID(A1;9;4);MID(A1;24;2);MID(A1;35;2))
```

[image: result in Calc]